# How to change color of first 2 letters using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Here is my code but it only change first character of the string

```
$string = 'Earrold Imperial Valdez';

$text = preg_replace('/(\b[a-z])/i','<span style="color:red;">\1</span>',$text);  
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take 2 character, e.g.

```
$text = preg_replace('/^([a-z]{2})/i','<span style="color:red;">\1</span>',$string);  
                     //↑      ^^^ Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 time
                     //| assert position at start of the string
```

Or if you want to do it without regex, you can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), e.g.

```
$text = '<span style="color:red;">' . substr($string, 0, 2) . '</span>' . substr($string, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks but how about if I want to change 2 characters every word. because it only change the first 2 character of the first word and the other words remain unchange.

Comment: @Earrold Then just don't use the anchor and keep your word boundary at the start of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your Regex. `[a-z]` will only affect one character, because there's no multiplier.  To change the first 2, you'll need to use a quantifier - `{}`.

Changing your RegExp to `/\b[a-z]{2})/i` should fix it.